# Find a formula for the magnitude of an arbitrary linear combination ax+by |||| Find the precise condition on $a, b, c$ and $d$ under which the lin....

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, vectors

Let x and y be two perpendicular unit vectors.
(a) Find a formula for the magnitude of an arbitrary linear combination ax+by of x and y in terms of a and b.

(b) Find the precise condition on a,b,c and d under which the linear combinations ax+by and cx+dy are perpendicular.

A purely geometric proof will not receive full credit; try to use vectors!

So far I know for the first one you have to use unit vectors but I'm not sure how to go forward. For the second one I'm quite confused in general. Could someone give me an explanation on these proofs. Thanks!